# Are there only four Digital ID providers for Office 2007/2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, digital-signature

Is there nobody else other than the four listed at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/CE001095531.aspx ?

I am not looking for a buying recommendation, just alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

No there are other companies that do it.

e.g
http://www.globalsign.co.uk/authentication-secure-email/digital-id/

http://www.avocosecure.com/htmlpages/products/signWordDocuments.html

Comment: Sorry, Joe, GlobalSign is already among the four listed, and Avocosecure is an Office 2003 add-on. Avocosecure mimics but doesn't use Office 2007's Digital ID feature.  Do you know any more?

Comment: Sorry completely missed Globalsign on that list. No others that I know of sorry although I bet Google knows more than me. :-)